# Twig is not able to load assets

Tags: php, twig, slim

I'm trying slim with slim-extras and twig. Problem is that I can't include css or js files into twig html. Accessing css and js file directly from browser give 404 not found error as well as browser console throws 404 page error.

here is my httdocs(folder structure)

[image]

My apache document root is `/var/www/devdomain.dev/public` and `DirectoryIndex index.php`

this is my index.php in public folder

here I tried to add hook with $app->hook and pass it to twig also did not work.

```php
<?php

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

// Prepare app
$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    'templates.path' => '../templates',
));

// Create monolog logger and store logger in container as singleton 
// (Singleton resources retrieve the same log resource definition each time)
$app->container->singleton('log', function () {
    $log = new \Monolog\Logger('slim-skeleton');
    $log->pushHandler(new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler('../logs/app.log', \Monolog\Logger::DEBUG));
    return $log;
});

$app->hook('slim.before', function () use ($app) {
    $app->view()->appendData(array('baseUrl' => 'templates/'));
});

// Prepare view
$app->view(new \Slim\Views\Twig());
$app->view->parserOptions = array(
    'charset' => 'utf-8',
    'cache' => realpath('../templates/cache'),
    'auto_reload' => true,
    'strict_variables' => false,
    'autoescape' => true
);
$app->view->parserExtensions = array(new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension());


// Define routes
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    // Sample log message
    $app->log->info("Home-Page '/' route");
    // Render index view
    $app->render('index.phtml');
});

// Run app
$app->run();
```

So my question is: how to pass template path or asset path to twig with slim?

edit: If css or js files in public folder they can be included.

Comment: what is the url of the 404 you get?

Comment: @inye it's www.devdomain.dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion it is about your setup. Your Browser is on `index.php` and from this he will search for your assets but can't find them - because they are not on your `vhost`.

Right physically they are there but when apache starts in the public folder your browser can not get out of there. That assets have to be public (or directly "echo-ed" into your template).